# Insert many json file inside one document in mongoDB

Tags: json, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a question:
but how can i insert many json files inside one document collection?
I have a ruby script connected with mongoDB which generate json files for each ID product.
In mongo i should want a structure like this:

```
Id(document's name) : {

many json for same ID

}
```

how can i get this structure in ruby?

DB's name is "test_db" and collection's name is "test_coll"

the code is:

```
Client = Mongo::Client.new([127.0.0.1:27017], :dtaabase => paperino)
json_array ={}
my_hash =Hash.new{}
my_array = Array.new
coll = Client[:ID_product]
```

add sensitive data for populate Json files

```
my_hash = JSON.parse(json_array.to_json)
my_array = my_hash
coll.update({{id: single_id_product} {"$push" => {json: 
my_array}},{upsert:true})
```

the ruby script generate more json files for 1 id_product

i want to save all json file for 1 product inside 1 document,
i try classic insert.many or insert one but doesnt work, because generate 1 doc for 1 json.

i try method $push for append all json array inside one document, but doesnt work too.

how can i do?
thanks

Comment: Can you show a more actual structure than this...sketch?

Comment: the actual structure of json for each ID_product , which is generated by ruby script, is:
 {
 number:10
 price:9
 }
 {
 number:9
 price:9
 }
 {
 number:10
 price:9
 }
 {
 number:10
 price: 10
 }
and this structure is an update on time of that ID_product.
in mongoDB i want a structure like this:

 {
  ID_product{ 
    number:10
    price:9
      }
      {
    numero:9
    price:9
       }...
in other words, i would want to insert more JSon file in a single document identified by ID_product

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the Ruby code that you are using to create the MongoDB document. You don't have to include any sensitive data but without code, we can hardly tell what's wrong.

Comment: i update the question, i hope in your help

Answer (score 0):

Documents in MongoDB are composed of field and value pairs. You typically have an `_id` field with an *ObjectID* value to identify the document and additional fields holding the document's data, e.g.:

```rb
doc =  {
  _id: BSON::ObjectId('650aeca18772677bb6613a89'),
  name: "foo"
}
```

The above document can then be inserted into a collection via [`insert_one`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ruby-driver/current/api/Mongo/Collection.html#insert_one-instance_method):

```rb
coll.insert_one(doc)
```

The same works for embedded data, e.g. an *array* called `data`:

```rb
doc =  {
  _id: BSON::ObjectId('650aee198772677bb6613a8a'),
  data: [
    { name: 'foo' },
    { name: 'bar' }
  ]
}

coll.insert_one(doc)
```

To append a new value to an existing array there's the [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator:

```rb
coll.update_one(
  { _id: BSON::ObjectId('650aee198772677bb6613a8a') },
  { '$push': { data: { name: 'baz' } } }
)
```

To [append multiple values to an array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array), you can use `$push` with the `$each` modifier:

```rb
coll.update_one(
  { _id: BSON::ObjectId('650aee198772677bb6613a8a') },
  { '$push': { data: { '$each': [ { name: 'qux' }, { name: 'quux' } ] } } }
)
```

The document after the above changes:

```rb
coll.find(_id: BSON::ObjectId('650aee198772677bb6613a8a')).first
#=> {
#     "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('650aee198772677bb6613a8a'),
#     "data"=>[
#       {"name"=>"foo"},
#       {"name"=>"bar"},
#       {"name"=>"baz"},
#       {"name"=>"qux"},
#       {"name"=>"quux"}
#     ]
#   }
```

Comment: ok, i tried to use insert_one(json_array), but mongo store them in different document, he make 1 document for each element of json array

Comment: i dont understand why doesnt work, i try every possible command but mongo doesnt store in 1 document this json array

Comment: @JACKoJONS you seem to be passing an array to `insert_one`. The method is supposed to be called with a _hash_ holding the data for a _single_ document. See my example above: `doc` is a hash, not an array.

Comment: ok thanks, but when i pass "my_hash", that is an hash of hash, i have the same problem. first line of hash save in 1 document and the same for other line of hash

Comment: and i try insert_one(my_hash)

Comment: How does `my_hash` look like? (don't paste a huge hash in the comments, update your question instead). Also, did you try to run my code? Does it work as expected? If so, you can use it as a starting point for your code.

Comment: i cant share sensible data but"my_hash" structure is like :   {"production" => {"value" => "0" ,"price" => "0"}, "type" =>"1"} , {"production1"  => {"value" => "1", "price" => "1"}, "type" => "2"}  etc.. for thousands of objects

Comment: but when i try to do insert_one(my_hash), mongo save 1 json object for 1 document, for example in this case mongo store document1:{{"production" => {"value" => "0" ,"price" => "0"}, "type" =>"1"} }, document2{ {"production1" => {"value" => "1", "price" => "1"}, "type" => "2"}}

Comment: and doesnt regroup all this objects inside 1 doc

Comment: Okay, and does my code above work for you? In particular the last example with `'$push': { data: { '$each': [...] } }`

Comment: i tried for the example of " embedded data, e.g. an array called data", but terminal say me "BSON::InvalidKey: hash instances are not allowed as keys in a Bson document"

Comment: i just write inside insert_one all doc content

Comment: and now im trying  '$push': { data: { '$each': [...] } }

Comment: Regarding the error: double check that you are running the very same code. Such error should not occur as I didn't use hashes as keys in my examples – the only keys are `_id` and `data`.

Comment: first example work, but when i run second example db cant create

Comment: but the script work

Comment: Now that you have a working script that can push multiple elements to an embedded document, it should be relatively easy to adapt it to your situation. Replace `data:` with the field name of your document's array and replace `[...]` with the actual array you want to append.

Comment: hi Stefan, i update you on this work, with the second example the script create db, but when i see, mongoDb store only the second_name "bar", soo strange, i hope in your help.

Comment: and this happen also when i replace variable with my variable and array, when i did this mongoDB store only the last json file, i try to change position for this code but when i run the script there is an "duplicateErrorCollection"

Comment: @JACKoJONS please edit your question and add the exact script you are running in a way that I can copy and paste it. Also include the document before and after the script.

Comment: ok stefan i try, change a part of code and all works fine, thank you so much. But now occur another problem: the document exceeds maximum allowed BSON object size after serialization

Comment: any suggestion for that?

Comment: @JACKoJONS if this answer solved the problem in your question, you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. With enough reputation, you can even upvote useful answers. Regarding your other problem: post a _new question_ for that.